# How to calculate exp(-1/x^2)?

Tags: c, numeric

I am looking for a clean way to compute precisely, when `x` is very close to zero:

```
exp(-1/x^2)
```

What is the best way (speed, precision, etc.)?

Comment: How large? Does `exp()` from <math.h> not give a precise result?

Comment: How precise do you want the result to be? `double` gives about 15 digits of precision; is that enough?

Comment: Did you try `long double ld = expl(-1./x/x)`?

Comment: @alk There's a typo in your comment.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: Where?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey it's evaluated left-to-right so `-1./x/x` becomes `(-1./x)/x` which is equal to -1/x².

Comment: @alk A million apologies.

Comment: Let's try this again.  exp() goes fast.  Exponentially fast.  A value of x = 0.01 already produces an incredibly low value of 1E-4343, too small to be computed in *double*.  The mistake is to look only at the term, not the entire expression where the term occurs.  A Taylor series approximation ought to bring relief.

Comment: @HansPassant: But wouldn't a taylor series converge poorly, because y = -1/x^2 is large in absolute value? - (In any case, as long as the OP does not explain what problems exactly occur and why the C-library math functions do not give the expected result, it is probably futile to guess about a solution.)

Comment: Ideally, yes 15 digits of precision would be enough. So the result should read like : 2.154778765434532E-367 for instance

Comment: @mellow Your example shows that you want to work with ranges outside of what the standard `double` type can represent (down to `1e-308` or some such). Can you use `long double` or `__float128` data types? In addition, are you using MS Visual Studio (this is important to know, because its `long double` type is useless)?

Comment: @mellow "2.154778765434532E-367" is 16 digits of precision.  True it has 15 digits after the decimal point, but [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(computer_science))  is the entire number.  In `printf()` there is a _precision_ field that controls the display of number of digits after the decimal point, but that is not the number's precision.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain precision at extreme x, handle the integer and fractional portion of `x` calculations separately.

```
// exp(-1/x^2)
void expm1overxx(double x, double *PowerOf10, double *FractionPowerOf10) {
  // Handle cases where x is not very close to zero
  // This path is not important for this answer, but here as a stub for later work.
  // For now, simple continue
  if (fabs(x) >= 1.0) {
    ;
  }
  static const double OneOverLn10 = 0.43429448190325182765112891891661;
  double y = -OneOverLn10/x/x;
  *PowerOf10 = floor(y);
  *FractionPowerOf10 = y - *PowerOf10;
}

void printf_expm1overxx(double x) {
  double PowerOf10, FractionPowerOf10;
  expm1overxx(x, &PowerOf10, &FractionPowerOf10);
  char buf[20];
  sprintf(buf, "%+0.15f", pow(10.0, FractionPowerOf10));
  printf("f(%10f) = %se%-8.0f. = %.15e\n", x, buf, PowerOf10, exp(-1/x/x));
}

void test_expm1overxx(void) {
  printf_expm1overxx(0.01);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.02);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.03);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.04);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.05);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.1);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.2);
  printf_expm1overxx(0.3);
  printf_expm1overxx(10);
}

       x             f(x)                     f(x) using exp(-1/x^2)
f(  0.010000) = +1.135483865314536e-4343   . = 0.000000000000000e+00
f(  0.020000) = +1.835672669162076e-1086   . = 0.000000000000000e+00
f(  0.030000) = +2.822121211968184e-483    . = 0.000000000000000e+00
f(  0.040000) = +3.680855854801760e-272    . = 3.680855854801800e-272
f(  0.050000) = +1.915169596714143e-174    . = 1.915169596714115e-174
f(  0.100000) = +3.720075976020902e-44     . = 3.720075976020889e-44
f(  0.200000) = +1.388794386496408e-11     . = 1.388794386496407e-11
f(  0.300000) = +1.494533852478144e-5      . = 1.494533852478143e-05
f( 10.000000) = +9.900498337491680e-1      . = 9.900498337491681e-01
```

There are some combining issues in the `printf()` that need to be addressed such as when the `pow(10, fraction)` of *very* close to 1.0, but need greater details of OP's intent and usage of "compute precisely".

Note: Given an proportional error in `x` as `err`, the proportional error in `exp(x)` is `err*exp(x)`.  By using extra precision, the potential for error and range can be mitigated, but not eliminated.  Finer control of the above `-OneOverLn10/x/x` can be had, but the overall solution is to somehow get extra precision.  The above takes advantage of using the integer and fractional parts of `y`

Answer (score 0):

Quickest:

```
        long double expatinfinity;

        /* can remove abs if x is strictly positive */
        if ( abs(x) < SENTINEL_VALUE)
           expatinfinity = 0;
        else
           expatinfinity = exp(-1.0/(x*x));
```

More precise (explicit power series):

```
        long double expatinfinity;
        long double t = 1.0/(x*x); /* be mindful of type */
        int n = 0;
        long double term;

        if( abs(x) < SENTINEL_VALUE)
           while(1){
               term = pow(-t,n)/fact(n);
               if(term < THRESHOLD) break;
               expatinfinity += term;
               ++n;
           }
        else
          expatinfinity = exp(-1.0/x*x);
```

`SENTINEL_VALUE` is a small value that determines the precision you want on the calculation and depends on the actual application (I'm guessing some gaussian statistics) `THRESHOLD` is basically the error you would want to tolerate on the taylor expansion. It is also dependant on the variable type you use and the precision your machine could provide. It can also depend on the ability to work consistently across various platforms. In other words, it depends a lot on the application.

Another way is to still perform the 1/x^2 -> t change of variable and only take the 1st order term (1 - t). Or choose a fixed number of terms from the taylor expansion. The disadvantage of this approach is uncontrolled precision but the advantage is constant time evaluation and you can store the expansion terms in an array and reuse them.

`fact` is a factorial function (N * (N -1) * (...) * 1). Don't remember if the math lib supply it. If not you will have to write it yourself. You will save memory if you don't use math.h and provide you own implementation.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. I do not think your method deals with the problem of x being close to zero, producing very very small outputs. I would not have posted this question otherwise ;)

Comment: Yes it does. That's the only thing I covered. Reread the answer. I will clarify some item and edit my answer.

Comment: Quick question: Do you know what is a taylor power serie?

Comment: Just for the record, the [Taylor/Maclaurin series is not going to help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Analytic_functions) unless you use some change of variable

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my post... (edit: I realise now I made a mistake in the taylor serie. It is fixed now)